# Jquery-confirm and passing POST variables to an externally loaded form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to send POST variables to an external PHP form?
I'd like to pass, in this example, XXX and YYY using POST (not GET).
I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/craftpip/jquery-confirm

```
<a id="btn" data-value1="XXX" data-value2="YYY">CLICK ME</a>

<script>
  $('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.confirm({
   title: 'Title',
   content: 'url:form.php',
   buttons: {
      ......
   }       
});
});
```

form.php:

```
<?php
 $value1 = $_POST['value1'];
 $value2 = $_POST['value2'];
?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Default values from parent page:</label>
    <input type="text" id="value1" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value1; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="value2" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value2; ?>">
</div>
```

UPDATE: tried this also, without success. Form doesn't load in modal:

```
content: function() { 
        var self = this;
            return $.ajax({
              url: 'form.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              async: false,
              method: 'post',
              data: { 'value1': 'XXX', 'value2': 'YYY' }
            }).done(function (response) {
                self.setContent(response);
            });
}
```

Comment: have you seen `$.post()`?

Comment: Check out the Ajax loading section in the documentation, it seems like you can insert jQuery $.ajax(), $.get(), $.post() etc: http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading

Comment: i've tried without success: content: function(){ return $.post( "form.php", { 'value1': 'XXX', 'value2': 'YYY' } ); },

Comment: What does "without success" mean? What is going wrong exactly? BW $.post doesn't return the server's response directly, it returns a Promise. This is because ajax is executed asynchronously on another thread, and you have to wait for that thread to return in order to get the server's response (at which point the Promise will be resolved). When using $.post (and other ajax methods) You specify a callback function which runs when the response is received and performs some action.  See the simple examples at https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ .

Comment: You can't simply set "content" as the return value of $.post. You're better off to run the $.post, and then within the "success" callback of that, define your confirm dialog, specifying the first param of the "success" callback as content

Comment: tiny nitpick grammar changes.

Comment: without success = form.php is not loaded inside modal. I've added new code, but it doesn't work

Comment: any errors in the console? Does the ajax actually run and get a response? Does the response look like what you expect etc etc. We need some proper debugging info, instead of just saying "doesn't work"

Comment: Sorry. Yes my RESPONSE is what I expected...but it doesn't appear inside the modal.

Comment: You are telling jQuery your `response` is in JSON format (`dataType: "json"`) but it looks like `form.php` returns HTML. So I think if you look in your browser's console you should have an error complaining that there's an error parsing the response as JSON. Try using `dataType: "html"` instead. Also please don't use `async:false` - it locks the browser while the request runs, making it feel to the user like it's crashed, so provides terrible UX. And it's deprecated and will stop working at some time in future - you will have a warning in your console about this too.

Comment: You should also consider adding a `.fail()` callback too, to deal with error conditions, as per the example at http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading (which I assume you were using as the basis for your code). That way if there's a problem with your server or the network, the user will get some feedback instead of being left simply with a non-functional page.

Comment: Thankyou. Problem was JSON instead of HTML format... ok for removing async:false

Comment: No problem. I have added it as the answer for you to accept, if you are able to do that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify

```
dataType: 'html'
```

instead of

```
dataType: 'json'
```

This is because `form.php` returns a HTML string, not a JSON object. You likely have an error in your console complaining that jQuery cannot parse the response as JSON, because it isn't JSON. If you tell jQuery to expect HTML instead, it will pass the reponse through as a string instead which you can directly display on screen, without trying to turn it into an object.